# Trouble taking in data correctly from command line

Tags: c++, loops, command-line

I'm trying to make my own version of wc (word count) in the terminal.
The user needs to be able to declare if they want to know the number of lines, characters, or words in there file. It will be entered in like this:

mywc -l -w -c

mywc -l -c     (is ok too)

mywc     (must calculate all)

Yet how can I make a loop (or whatever I need to do ) that will only do the calculations if necessary.

The only idea I've been able to come up with would be to loop through **argv and see if I can find -l -w or a -c and then do if statements after that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        string l = "-l";
        string w = "-w";
        string c = "-c";

        if(argv[i] == l)cout <<"detected -l" << endl;
        else if(argv[i] == w)cout <<"detected -w" << endl;
        else if(argv[i] == c)cout <<"detected -c" << endl;
        else  
            cout <<"Must calculate all" << endl;
            break;
    }
    return(0);
```

My problem is once it finds one of the strings it breaks the loop and I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the "break" is not enclosed in the "else" statement.

This is why it is always a good idea to use brackets for any if/else/while construct; it is easy to visually miss a bug like this.

Edit: Even with the bracket fix, your code will not run as you describe.
With the bracket fix, your code will interpret any unexpected argument to mean "must calculate all". If you want "no arguments" to mean "must calculate all", you should add an if statement to check if `argc == 1` outside the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're also coding in python (either that or you just forget the brackets), you've written:

```
else
  cout <<"Must calculate all" << endl;
  break;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
else
{
  cout <<"Must calculate all" << endl;
}
break;
```

in C++.
The break is always executed at each iteration of the loop (so it executes only once).
What you want is:

```
else
{
  cout <<"Must calculate all" << endl;
  break;
}
```

(also, you forgot to copy one `}` after the `return 0;`)

Comment: Cool, every option is working now except when I just type 'mywc'. When I only type 'mywc' there is no error it just closes the program.

Comment: Of course: if you don't provide any argument you now iterate from i = 1 to i = 0 (i < 1, because argc = 1) so it doesn't execute the loop at all